# How to build tuple array variable of integers + strings in python for loop?

Tags: python, django, string, variables, integer

Manually built variable STAFFLIST works in django database as a list of choices listed as PositiveSmallIntegerField.

```
STAFF1 = 1
STAFF2 = 2
STAFF3 = 3
STAFFLIST = (
    (STAFF1, _('John Doe')),
    (STAFF2, _('Lisa Beauty')),
    (STAFF3, _('Harry Potter')),
)
```

Print for this variable works as follows:

```
>>>print(STAFFLIST[1])
(2, 'Lisa Beauty')
>>> print(STAFFLIST[1][0])
2
>>> print(STAFFLIST[1][1])
Lisa Beauty
>>>
```

How to built this variable automatically in for loop based on the actual list of staffs? I was trying something like below, but unsuccsessful:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
idx=0
for stf in staff:
    STAFFLIST[idx] = (stf.id, _(stf.first_name + ' ' + stf.last_name))
    idx=idx+1
```

I am getting error like:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I believe, my problem is low knowledge level of python datatypes. And currently, I am trying to work with tuple datatype and to store string inside.

Comment: Can you not use a `ForeignKey` for a model or a `ModelChoiceField` for a form?

Comment: 100s different ways exist to solve simple task. The "choice" files should serve to identify in admin database the staff who sovled customer's task. I have inspired myself at [Built-in Django solutions](https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-models-declaring-list-available-choices-right-way/). I want dynamic STAFFLIST because it can change. It should be independent on the fact if `PositiveSmallIntegerField` or `ModelChoiceField` is used. When I can build the variable manually, it has to be possible to do it automatically in the for loop. I find it more basic python than django issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the for loop problem. Folowing code works and builds the same tuple array as the manually defined variable:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
idx=0
for stf in staff:
    if idx == 0:
        STAFFLIST = ((stf.id, _(stf.first_name + ' ' + stf.last_name)),)
        idx=1
    else:
        STAFFLIST = STAFFLIST + ((stf.id, _(stf.first_name + ' ' + stf.last_name)),)
```